# difference between windows 7 (64bit)enterrprise and windows 7 (64bit)professional Unable to create folder under c:\Program Files

Tags: virtualization, permissions, uac, windows-7

This is related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4721604/windows-7-64bit-win32-api-to-sacrificerelegate-administrative-privileges-for

Posting here to get more idea about UAC with respect windows 7 variants

I have two machines. 
a -  Uses windows 7 Enterprise 64 bit
b -  Uses windows 7 Professional 64 bit.

In machine  'a' I can create folders under c:\Program Files\ , In machine 'b' this gives permission error.

```
cd /d c:\Program Files
touch test   (permission denied with windows 7 professional)
```

It is related to windows 7 UAC and virtualization. A search on web points to lot of articles but I could not figure out where the above difference is documented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is almost no difference between enterprise and professional. Enterprise is just pro with added Bitlocker and a few license tweaks to make it more palatable to corporate customer. It's typically shipped to those buying Windows 7 with Software Assurance through volume license agreements.

There should be no difference in the behaviour of UAC on those two. The default setting will prevent writing to Program Files in both cases.

Some thoughts on what to look at: If you're running `touch`, then can I assume you're running under Cygwin? Check that you're running both shells are running elevated, that the UAC settings are identical (after a reboot), and that there's no group policy application getting in the way. (Though it would be odd for a GPO to differentiate between two editions of windows, they could be in different OUs in your domain for some reason).